# Implementing Digest Authentication in Play Framework 2.x

Tags: java, playframework, digest-authentication

I have a RESTful service I am implementing in Play 2.5.x that needs to replace an existing server that implements authentication with Digest.  Does anyone have a tutorial or example of how to implement this with Play?

Basically the client says something like:

```
POST /tui/testing/v1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: dev01.funkyhost.org
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 0
```

the server has to reply with a request with:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="SomeFunkyRealm", nonce="ST8RrC0/BQA=9f0890ed9f1603989a4526ce2d27f4415fef88c6", algorithm=MD5, qop="auth"
```

and the client will reply with something like:

```
POST /tui/testing/v1/ HTTP/1.1
Host: dev01.funkyhost.org
Authorization: Digest username="testing", realm="SomeFunkyRealm", nonce="7VKfAjI/BQA=5a86a2b75bb70c9aa0723b8eaed002d919bd3039",
uri="/tui/testing/v1/", cnonce="MWE4OThmYTE2NTFkZTg2YjYyYzhhMTA1OWVhMzIxODU=", nc=00000001, qop=auth, response="722260be15837dead193763511604850", algorithm="MD5"
User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 117938
Expect: 100-continue
....
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

See [Chapter 2](https://github.com/spinscale/play-cookbook) of Alexander's book. He provides a working application for doing this, albeit in quite a dated version of the framework.

Depending on what version you are using you will need to play (pardon the pun) with some of the imports, since they will have shifted a bit since he wrote this, and do a bit of refactoring.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I did see that example in Play 1 but Play 2 does things so radically different I was not able to translate it over.  I ended up using Apache for proxying requests to Play, and turning on Digest Authentication on the Apache side instead.  I'd rather get it working natively in Play but I'll just need to accept this workaround for now.